# Check multiple conditions at once using m4 preprocessor

Tags: preprocessor, m4

There is any m4 syntax that is equivalent to this C preprocessor one?

```
#if defined A || defined B
do something
#endif
```

Comment: Sure, m4 has `||` - check out `ifelse` and `eval` also - some useful notes here: http://mbreen.com/m4.html

Comment: Can you provide an example?
I have tried something like this but it did not work
`ifelse(eval(A==1) || eval(B==1),1,
echo true,
echo false
)`

Comment: The `||` needs to be inside the `eval`: `ifelse(eval(A==1 || B==1), 1, echo true, echo false )`

Comment: Thanks Paul. The only issue with your code is that both A and B need to be defined otherwise you'll get this error if, for example, only A is defined:
    
`m4:test.m4:7: bad expression in eval (bad input): 1==1 || B==1`

Comment: Sure - you can add some further tests to make sure A and B are both defined first to handle this possibility if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

The long answer:

## Checking if macros are defined

```
define(`defined', `ifelse($1()$1, `$1()$1', ``0'', ``1'')')

ifelse(eval(defined(`A') || defined(`B')),
       1,
       ``At least one is defined'',
       ``Neither are defined'')
```

There are no sensible ways to check for a defined macro in m4, so you would have to resort to hacks like the above.

## How it works

`ifelse` checks for equality of two strings. In the `defined` macro, I've expanded the macro in `$1` twice (once as `$1()`, once as `$1`). I'm comparing it against `$1()$1` as a string, so if it doesn't expand then it will compare true. The reason for specifying the macros in two different ways is because `A` could be defined as ``` ``A'' ``` or ``` ``A()'' ``` which would otherwise cause false negatives when using this method to check whether or not it is defined.

I'm then using that `defined` macro within an `eval` to throw the `||` logic on top.

### Caveats

- If you use the word `defined` in your document already, you might want to give the macro a different name.
- The `defined` macro *will not work* on macros defined to expand to unquoted syntactic markers like `(`, `,`, or `)`.
- If the macro to be checked is infinitely recursive, the `defined` check will also never return. (Essentially, realize that a hack like this is still actually executing the macro.)

Though the last 2 points there are something you'd expect from any `ifelse` check on a macro, it might not be intuitive to expect it from a macro purporting to check for whether another macro is defined.

## A better way

I would much rather suggest that you define the variables with some default value first, and just avoid the problem of checking whether it is defined or not altogether.

This is much easier to do:

```
# Define this right off the bat:
define(`A', ``0'')

# Maybe later this line will come up...
# Quotes around the A are mandatory
define(`A', ``1'')

# Then soon after that, you can check:
ifelse(A, `0', , ``hey, A is nonzero!'')
```